# python code highlighter for publishing in html

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting

I'm looking for a python code highlighter for publishing as html. I've found this site http://quickhighlighter.com that does highlighting really well. However if I try to copy/paste some python code from it to a text file, I get a mess. If you know a better tool, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It becomes a mess you say... What editor is that?

Comment: I meant that when I copy python code from a webpage generated by quickhighlighter tool, line numbers and other junk are copied as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which syntax-highlighter with export to HTML (for blog) to choose?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112314/which-syntax-highlighter-with-export-to-html-for-blog-to-choose)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`pygmentize`](http://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/), which handles a lot more languages than just Python and a lot more formats than just HTML.

Answer (score 4):

Don't get messed up with http://quickhighlighter.com  I've used this too
But I would suggest http://hilite.me/

If you are looking to highlight the code which is in your `<code>` or `<pre>` block you can use https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/  This works well and has a lot of themes.
This prettifier looks for the code block with class "prettyprint" and highlights the code.