# Open source browser based (i.e. javascript) highlighter for Python code?

Tags: javascript, codehighlighter

I have an html page with a textarea in which users type python code.  I'd like for the input python code to be highlighted as they type, much as a desktop-based IDE would do.

Unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889841/python-code-highlighter-for-publishing-in-html), I don't want the code to be passed to the server and returned highlighted - I'd like for it all to be done by javascript in the browser.

Rather than re-invent the wheel, is there an existing open source javascript library which would do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit more googling, and to answer my own question - wikipedia has a [comparison of javascript source code editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors) and [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) seems to be a popular choice.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Mozilla Bespin (now called Skywriter) https://mozillalabs.com/skywriter/

I'm fairly sure it highlights Python